# Can a web server prevent pages it serves from installing service workers?

Tags: service-worker, ipfs, websecurity

Suppose there is a web server that hosts arbitrary user-controlled content under some paths - public IPFS gateways are the example that got me thinking about this. Is it possible for that server to prevent pages that it serves from installing service workers on clients (and thus spoofing content for non-user-controlled paths)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some helpful info [in the service worker specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-script-request):

> An HTTP request to fetch a service worker's script resource will
>   include the following header:
>
> `Service-Worker` Indicates this request is a service worker's script
>   resource request.
>
> Note: This header helps administrators log the requests and detect
>   threats.

If you'd like to make sure that your web server doesn't allow any service worker registrations, one approach would be to check for the `Service-Worker` header on incoming requests and have your web server return an appropriate HTTP error response (anything `4xx` or `5xx` would work—maybe `403` or `412`?) whenever you detect that.